# Will uninstall/reinstall of VMware Tools disrupt a production VM with an E1000 NIC?

Tags: vmware-esxi

A software vendor is urging us to change from the E1000 vNIC to a VMXNET3 on our primary app server. Our CEO has asked me to do it ASAP, so over lunch in about an hour here. I have added the VMXNET3 vNIC to the VM, but the drivers are not loading and so I need to reinstall VMware Tools (it's already up-to-date).

I know it requires a reboot which I will do in my maintenance window over lunch, but does simply reinstalling VMware Tools disrupt a VM that only uses a E1000 vNIC? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reinstalling VMware Tools should not 'disrupt' a VM using only an E1000 vNIC (it shouldn't change the MAC address or hardware slot ID).

Comment: Thank you, Pak. I went ahead with the procedure and everything went fine, although a reboot of the VM was necessary to install VMware Tools and load the VMXNET3 driver.